# How to add a class to Cocos2d-Box2d in my project.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

There is a box2d class b2loopShape that I want to use in my app but it is not included in box2d any longer. I found a copy of the class but when I try to add it to my project I get like 45 errors. Any suggestions of intructions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try addressing the errors it gave you?

Comment: b2LoopShape is part of the latest source in svn. Perhaps you just need a full update: http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FBox2D%2FBox2D%2FCollision%2FShapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only reliable way you have to do that is using the last Box2D version that also included that class. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2LoopShape.cpp?r=109), I see that it was version 2.1.0 (but I cannot guarantee it). Version 2.0.1 is available for download as a zip file, otherwise you should use svn checkout.

Comment: A better idea in my opinion is to rewrite the class using the old class as a reference.

Comment: @Aaron Goselin: nothing against it, but one should understand why that class was removed in the first place and possibly it is not trivial at all. Anyway, it can be tried.

Comment: Yes, fair enough.  It all depends on the OP's skill level I suppose.